# Xalan-J: resolve the namespace of a QName text value within an extension function

Tags: java, xml, xslt, xml-namespaces, xalan

I've implemented a simple XPath extension function that is intended to be invoked by Xalan-J during an XSLT transformation. The invocation part is trivial, but what I do not understand is how the implementation of the function is supposed to access the namespace context of the document being transformed (not the context of transformation, supplied as the first argument to extension functions). I need this context in order to resolve namespaces of element text values that are actually QNames.

Here is an example document that needs to be transformed:

```xml
<document xmlns='org.stackoverflow.example.document'>
    <element xmlns:value="org.stackoverflow.example.value">value:some-value</element>
</document>
```

The `value:some-value` is an example of a QName text value I'd like to resolve - it represents `some-value` in `org.stackoverflow.example.value` namespace.

The transformation looks like this:

```xml
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl='http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform'
                xmlns:sofun='xalan://org.stackoverflow.example.XPathFunctionQNameTextValueResolver'
                xmlns:doc='org.stackoverflow.example.document'>
    <xsl:template match='/doc:document/doc:element'>
        <xsl:value-of select='sofun:resolveQNameTextValue(.)' />
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

It essentially just calls my extension function with node `element` as the only argument.

So the actual code looks like this (requires Xalan-J 2.7.1 in your classpath):

```java
package org.stackoverflow.example;

import java.io.*;
import javax.xml.transform.*;
import javax.xml.transform.stream.*;
import org.apache.xalan.extensions.ExpressionContext;
import org.w3c.dom.NamedNodeMap;
import org.w3c.dom.Node;
import org.w3c.dom.traversal.NodeIterator;

public class XPathFunctionQNameTextValueResolver {
    
    public static final boolean resolveQNameTextValue(ExpressionContext ctx, NodeIterator nodes) {        
        Node node = nodes.nextNode();
        while (node != null) {
            if (node.hasChildNodes()) {
                String textValue = node.getFirstChild().getNodeValue();
                String[] pfxAndName = textValue.split(":");
                String prefix = "";
                String name = textValue;
                if (pfxAndName.length == 2) {
                    prefix = pfxAndName[0];
                    name = pfxAndName[1];
                }
                String namespace = node.lookupNamespaceURI(prefix);
                // "namespace" is always null, unless null is supplied as "prefix", which returns the default namespace
                NamedNodeMap attributes = node.getAttributes();
                if (attributes != null) {
                    // "attributes" does not contain any "xmlns" attributes
                }
                System.out.println(
                        String.format(
                                "namespace: %s, prefix:%s, local-name: %s, attributes-len: %d", 
                                namespace, prefix, name, attributes != null ? attributes.getLength() : 0));
            }
            node = nodes.nextNode();
        }
        
        return false;
    }
    
    public static void main(String[] args) throws TransformerConfigurationException, TransformerException {
        String xslt = "" +
"<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl='http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform'\n" +
"                xmlns:sofun='xalan://org.stackoverflow.example.XPathFunctionQNameTextValueResolver'\n" +
"               xmlns:doc='org.stackoverflow.example.document'>\n" +
"   <xsl:template match='/doc:document/doc:element'>\n" +
"       <xsl:value-of select='sofun:resolveQNameTextValue(.)' />\n" +
"   </xsl:template>\n" +
"</xsl:stylesheet>";
        String document = "" +
"<document xmlns='org.stackoverflow.example.document'>\n" +
"   <element xmlns:value=\"org.stackoverflow.example.value\">value:some-value</element>\n" +
"</document>";
        
        TransformerFactory xalanTransFact = new org.apache.xalan.processor.TransformerFactoryImpl();
        Templates template = xalanTransFact.newTemplates(new StreamSource(new StringReader(xslt)));
        
        StringWriter writer = new StringWriter();
        Transformer transformer = template.newTransformer();
        transformer.transform(new StreamSource(new StringReader(document)), new StreamResult(writer));
    }
    
}
```

The expectation was that `node.lookupNamespaceURI(prefix)` would provide the namespace I need, but this is not the case. The `node` is actually a node in a DOM model, but these nodes do not seem to contain any namespace information. It's like the parser that produces these nodes is misconfigured and ignores namespaces entirely.

How do I change my example so that namespace information is present when the implementation of the XPath function executes at runtime?

Comment: Do you get the namespace information if instead of a StreamSource you could a DOMSource with a DocumentBuilder explicitly set up to support namespaces?

Comment: @MartinHonnen, oh, man. This is embarrassing. You are correct - parsing the document with a namespace aware DocumentBuilderFactory solves the issue.

Comment: In the Java world it is also easy to switch to Saxon 9 or 10 and XSLT 2 or 3 where you don't need an extension function with e.g. `<xsl:value-of select='namespace-uri-from-QName(resolve-QName(., .))' />`.

Comment: @MartinHonnen, not in my case, unfortunately. My actual extension functions represent a core function library of a standard I'm implementing. It's one of the rare cases, where extensions are actually warranted, not just a workaround for choosing the wrong processor...

Answer (score 0):

As per a suggestion from @MartinHonnen in a comment, you need to supply a namespace aware input document parser yourself, if you need namespaces:

```java
DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
factory.setNamespaceAware(true);
DocumentBuilder builder = factory.newDocumentBuilder();
Document parse = builder.parse(new InputSource(new StringReader(document)));
transformer.transform(new DOMSource(parse), new StreamResult(writer));
```

Corrected example:

```java
package org.stackoverflow.example;

import java.io.*;
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder;
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory;
import javax.xml.parsers.ParserConfigurationException;
import javax.xml.transform.*;
import javax.xml.transform.dom.DOMSource;
import javax.xml.transform.stream.*;
import org.apache.xalan.extensions.ExpressionContext;
import org.w3c.dom.Document;
import org.w3c.dom.NamedNodeMap;
import org.w3c.dom.Node;
import org.w3c.dom.traversal.NodeIterator;
import org.xml.sax.InputSource;
import org.xml.sax.SAXException;

public class XPathFunctionQNameTextValueResolver {
    
    public static final boolean resolveQNameTextValue(ExpressionContext ctx, NodeIterator nodes) {        
        Node node = nodes.nextNode();
        while (node != null) {
            if (node.hasChildNodes()) {
                String textValue = node.getFirstChild().getNodeValue();
                String[] pfxAndName = textValue.split(":");
                String prefix = "";
                String name = textValue;
                if (pfxAndName.length == 2) {
                    prefix = pfxAndName[0];
                    name = pfxAndName[1];
                }
                String namespace = node.lookupNamespaceURI(prefix);
                // "namespace" is always null, unless null is supplied as "prefix", which returns the default namespace
                NamedNodeMap attributes = node.getAttributes();
                if (attributes != null) {
                    // "attributes" does not contain any "xmlns" attributes
                }
                System.out.println(
                        String.format(
                                "namespace: %s, prefix:%s, local-name: %s, attributes-len: %d", 
                                namespace, prefix, name, attributes != null ? attributes.getLength() : 0));
            }
            node = nodes.nextNode();
        }
        
        return false;
    }
    
    public static void main(String[] args) throws TransformerConfigurationException, TransformerException, ParserConfigurationException, IOException, SAXException {
        String xslt = "" +
"<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl='http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform'\n" +
"                xmlns:sofun='xalan://org.stackoverflow.example.XPathFunctionQNameTextValueResolver'\n" +
"               xmlns:doc='org.stackoverflow.example.document'>\n" +
"   <xsl:template match='/doc:document/doc:element'>\n" +
"       <xsl:value-of select='sofun:resolveQNameTextValue(.)' />\n" +
"   </xsl:template>\n" +
"</xsl:stylesheet>";
        String document = "" +
"<document xmlns='org.stackoverflow.example.document'>\n" +
"   <element xmlns:value=\"org.stackoverflow.example.value\">value:some-value</element>\n" +
"</document>";
        
        TransformerFactory xalanTransFact = new org.apache.xalan.processor.TransformerFactoryImpl();
        Templates template = xalanTransFact.newTemplates(new StreamSource(new StringReader(xslt)));
        
        StringWriter writer = new StringWriter();
        Transformer transformer = template.newTransformer();
        
        DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        factory.setNamespaceAware(true);
        DocumentBuilder builder = factory.newDocumentBuilder();
        Document parse = builder.parse(new InputSource(new StringReader(document)));
        
        transformer.transform(new DOMSource(parse), new StreamResult(writer));
    }
    
}
```